# Background task-processing package for Heroku/Java

Tags: java, task-management

I've deployed a lot of sites to Heroku using Python + Django.  When I need to do background/asynchronous processing, I reach for Django-RQ or Dramatiq.

Now I've been asked to implement something similar, but using Java/Groovy as my language.  The only similar thing I've been able to find is "IronWorker", which seems to require me to learn Docker as well.

What's the simplest thing that could possibly work?